# How to insert two strings into my Access database from Java using UCanAccess?

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, ucanaccess

I am trying to add two strings on two separate columns columns of my database using Java but I'm not sure what I am doing wrong. The code I am using

```
 try{
    Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(
                "jdbc:ucanaccess://C:/Users/nevik/Desktop/databaseJava/Employee.accdb");
        Statement st = conn.createStatement();
        String sql = "Select * from Table2";
        ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(sql);


        rs.updateString("user", user);
        rs.updateString("pass", pass);

        rs.updateRow();

    }
    catch(SQLException ex){
        System.err.println("Error: "+ ex);
    }
```

The first column on my database is `user` and the next one is `pass`. I am using UCanAccess in order to access my database.

Answer (score 1):

This is how you normally update a row in java:

```
String query = "update Table2 set user = ?, pass= ?";
PreparedStatement preparedStmt = conn.prepareStatement(query);
preparedStmt.setInt   (1, user);
preparedStmt.setString(2, pass);

// execute the java preparedstatement
preparedStmt.executeUpdate();
```

Answer (score 1):

First of, you've not updated the position of the current cursor in the `ResultSet`, which means that it's pointing to nothing...

You could use...

```
if (rs.next()) {
   rs.updateString("user", user);
   rs.updateString("pass", pass);
   rs.updateRow();
}
```

But this assumes two things...

1. You have a database that supports updating values in the `ResultSet` and
2. You want to update the existing values.

To insert a value into the database, you should be using the `INSERT` command, for example...

```
try(Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(
            "jdbc:ucanaccess://C:/Users/nevik/Desktop/databaseJava/Employee.accdb")) {
    try (PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement("INSERT into Table2 (user, pass) VALUES (?, ?)") {
        stmt.setString(1, user);
        stmt.setString(2, pass);
        int rowsUpdated = stmt.executeUpdate();
    }
}
catch(SQLException ex){
    System.err.println("Error: "+ ex);
}
```

You might like to take some time to go over a basic [SQL](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/) tutorial and the [JDBC(TM) Database Access](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/) trail

As a side note...

1. You should not be storing passwords in `String`s, you should keep them in `char` arrays and
2. You should not be storing passwords in the database without encrypting them in some way

Comment: setString is asking me to pass an int for the first argument

Comment: updated the try clause
try(Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(
"jdbc:ucanaccess://C:/Users/nevik/Desktop/databaseJava/Employee.accdb")) {
     try (PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement("INSERT into Table2 (user, pass) VALUES ("+user+", "+pass+")")) {
                    stmt.setString(1, user);
                    stmt.setString(2, pass);
                    stmt.executeUpdate();
    }


got error:  net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessSQLException: user lacks privilege or object not found: USER12

I cant seem to figure out what USER12 is referring to

Comment: The `try-with-resources` demonstrated in the answer is only available in Java 7+

Comment: user and pass are the variables that i used to get from the user to the program

Comment: Yes, but `PreparedStaments` bind the variables to the parameters positions, that's what the `setString` calls are for.  Take a few minutes to read [How to use Prepared Statements](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html).  Thought I had linked it, sorry

Comment: @guevarak12 Anyway, if you use a simple Statement (not a PreparedStatement)
you need String delimeters around your values:
not ("+user+", "+pass+") but  ('"+user+"', '"+pass+"') .

Comment: @jamadei And risk potential SQL injection, this is bad idea generally, and a bad practice professional

Comment: @MadProgrammer yes, of course, that's right, the use of PreparedStatement is a good practice and it's useful to avoid some risks
(e.g., SQLInjection in a web application).
Only I wanted to correct a formal error.

Answer (score 1):

@guevarak12 
About the original question (how to use updatable ResultSet): 
your code is wrong, you have to move the cursor in the right position.
In particular, if you are inserting a new row you have to call  rs.moveToInsertRow(); before  rs.updateString("user", user).
If you are updating an existent row, you have to move the cursor calling rs.next() and so reach the row to update.
Also you have to create the Statement in a different way:

Statement st =conn.createStatement( ResultSet.TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY,          ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);

See junit examples  in the UCanAccess source distribution, class net.ucanaccess.test.CrudTest.
All other comments seem to be correct.