# null pointer exception while inserting in Ms access table

Tags: java, ms-access, jdbc

I am trying the following code to insert in MS Access table through ucanaccess jdbc. It gives the following exception. I am stuck where i am doing wrong.The exception is:

```
>net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessSQLException: UCAExc:::3.0.3 java.lang.NullPointerException java.lang.NullPointerException
    at net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessStatement.executeQuery(UcanaccessStatement.java:211)   at net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessStatement.executeQuery(UcanaccessStatement.java:211)
    at insertdata.jButton1ActionPerformed(insertdata.java:197)
    at insertdata.access$200(insertdata.java:15)
    at insertdata$3.actionPerformed(insertdata.java:64)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2346)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
    at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mouseReleased(AWTEventMulticaster.java:289)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6525)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3321)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6290)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2234)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4881)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2292)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4703)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4898)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4533)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4462)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2278)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2739)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4703)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:746)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$400(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:697)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:691)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:719)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:717)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:716)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: java.lang.NullPointerException java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCUtil.sqlException(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCUtil.sqlException(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCStatement.fetchResult(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCStatement.executeQuery(Unknown Source)
    at net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessStatement.executeQuery(UcanaccessStatement.java:208)
    ... 40 more
Caused by: org.hsqldb.HsqlException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.hsqldb.error.Error.error(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.result.Result.newErrorResult(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.StatementDMQL.execute(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.Session.executeCompiledStatement(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.Session.executeDirectStatement(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.Session.execute(Unknown Source)
    ... 43 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessConnection.getCtxConnection(UcanaccessConnection.java:81)
    at net.ucanaccess.triggers.TriggerAutoNumber.fire(TriggerAutoNumber.java:39)
    at org.hsqldb.TriggerDef.pushPair(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.Table.fireTriggers(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.StatementDML.insertSingleRow(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.StatementInsert.getResult(Unknown Source)
    ... 47 more
```

Any suggestions how can i solve this. And is my query creating problem?

**Code**

```
 private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         

        try{
            conn=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:ucanaccess://E:/cars.accdb");
            st=conn.createStatement();
             String name=tname.getText();
             String email=temail.getText();
             int phone=Integer.parseInt( tphone.getText());

             String sql="insert into customers ([name],[email],[phone]) values('name','email',phone)";
            rs= st.executeQuery(sql);
             if(rs.next())
             {
                System.out.println("updated!!");
             }
              st.close();
              conn.close();
        }
         catch(Exception e){

        System.out.println(e);

    }
    }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a Null Pointer Exception, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-null-pointer-exception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: @YoungHobbit it doesn't helped me

Comment: use `e.printStackTrace()` to learn what line is causing the error

Comment: @wero i did so and it says `rs= st.executeQuery(sql)` this line is creating problem

Comment: @BalusC null is at the query and i am not getting the problem. I am new to this.

Comment: Doesn't it require `Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");?`

Comment: @debin No i am using UcanAccess and it doesn't need this

Comment: @tabia include the full stacktrace in the query

Comment: `conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:ucanaccess://words.accdb;jackcessOpener=CryptCodecOpener", "user", "pass");` so u dont need of user n pass also?

Comment: @debin no i don't need it. This thing works perfect when i apply `select` query. But for `insert` it is creating problem

Comment: may b http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24502234/how-to-insert-two-strings-into-my-access-database-from-java-using-ucanaccess can help u

Comment: @debin this solved the issue. The problem was i was inserting in a wrong way

Comment: @tabia glad it helped uh :)

Answer (score 2):

Your error is that you execute a SQL INSERT using `executeQuery`.

Use

```
st.executeUpdate(sql);
```

instead.

Unfortunately the JDBC driver doesn't give you a proper error message but apparently fails deep down in its internals.